# White Screen When Adding New Field in Freeform Pro

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am running EE 2.7.2 on a GoDaddy server and I'm attempting to create a new field in Solspace Freeform Pro 4.1.3. I get a white screen after clicking the New Field button. I believe I recall a comment in the Solspace weekly chat that there may be some issues with this combination...GoDaddy being the main issue. Has anyone run into this or aware of any fixes? Thanks!

Comment: Please post what you have tried already please...

Answer (score 1):

> "Blank pages in ExpressionEngine, where the source is also empty, are
>   usually the result of a suppressed PHP error."

Here are instructions for troubleshooting blank pages in EE:
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/troubleshooting/general/blank_pages.html

Answer (score 0):

Just to give up an update here. It seems like it was a rare occurrence, but the team at Solspace did make some updates to the code on my installation which will be a part of the next patch.